# Запятая перед чем

Tags: пунктуация

Говори да чаще(,) чем нет.

Нужна ли запятая?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А по-моему, у нас не сравнительный оборот, а придаточное в СПП. Запятая нужна.

> Сравнительные придаточные могут быть неполными: в них опускается
>   сказуемое, если оно совпадает со сказуемым главного предложения.
>
> Например: Существование его заключено в эту тесную программу, как яйцо
>   в скорлупу. (А. Чехов)
>
> О том, что это именно неполное двусоставное предложение
>   свидетельствует второстепенный член группы сказуемого - в скорлупу.
>
> Неполные сравнительные придаточные не следует путать со сравнительными
>   оборотами, в которых не может быть сказуемого.
>
> Необходимо разграничивать придаточное сравнительное и сравнительный
>   оборот. В придаточном сравнительном присутствует сказуемое или
>   второстепенные члены группы сказуемого, то есть зависимые от
>   сказуемого слова. В сравнительном обороте группа сказуемого не
>   представлена.

***Говори "да" чаще, чем (говоришь) "нет".***

> ***Чем*** является союзом в придаточных таких сложноподчинённых предложений, которые ***имеют в главной части*** прилагательное,
>   ***наречие в сравнительной степени***...

Comment: Да, Вы правы, большое спасибо за поправку. Буду внимательнее.Исправлю ответ.

Comment: Серж, я не уверена, я вся имхо! )))

Comment: Галина, вы правы: это ПСП, во второй части пропущен глагол ''говоришь''Ср.: Широкие тени ходят по равнине, как облака по небу (Чехов) – опущено сказуемое ходят.

Comment: А ещё я добавила - как аргумент в пользу СПП - про сравнительную степень.

Comment: Да, Галина. Я тоже хотел добавить, но вы меня опередили. ))

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна. Т. к. оборот с ***чем*** образует сравнительную конструкцию в составе придаточного. Иными словами - это придаточное сравнительное предложение.

Comment: Простите, что не по теме, Серж, только меня удивляет, что Вы писали о том, что сокращения надо писать с пробелами, а сами же пишете "т. к." без. Или Вы в спешке не обращаете на пробелы внимания?

Comment: Очень интересно, почему, прямо интригующе!..

Comment: Не понял, что за второе поле, хм...

Comment: Артем, когда будете писать ответ  на вопрос  - увидите.